# Tslint Argument of type "x" is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

Tags: angular, tslint

On Project first build I get following errors on terminal and cannot be accessed on the browser. But once I hot reload the project I can then access it in browser but the error is still shown in TsLint.

[image]

```
//Event Emmitter
@Output() closeOrderSummary = new EventEmitter<string>();
@Output() checkoutCart = new EventEmitter<string>();
@Output() updateItemQty = new EventEmitter<string>();
@Output() updateProductSelected = new EventEmitter<string>();

//Event Emit function
onUpdateItemCount(item, direc) {
  const payload = { item, direc };
  this.updateItemQty.emit(payload);
}

onUpdateProductSelected(value, item) {
  const payload = { value, item};
  this.updateProductSelected.emit(payload);
}
```

Comment: please share your code with EventEmitter Objects.

Comment: @DomadiyaBhautik I've updated my post with EventEmitter Objects. I guess it happened due to the <string> definition in EventEmitter right?

Comment: change type of EventEmitter Object from string to Object or any type

Answer (score 0):

Your updateItemQty and updateProductSelected outputs are defined like string, and you are sending an Object type. Try to modify the attributes definition type to match when you emit the value